# RxJS emit values from array every x seconds, call a function with that value, retry if failed

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs5

I have an array, the type of the values is irrelevant. What I would like to do is emitting one value every x seconds, call a function with that value, and if that function failed for some reason, retry it after y seconds (can be a simple constant, no need for any incremental thing here).

What I have so far

```
Rx.Observable
    .interval(500)
    .take(arr.length)
    .map(idx => arr[idx])
    .flatMap(dt => randomFunc(dt))
    .catch(e => conosle.log(e))
    .retry(5)
    .subscribe();

function randomFunc(dt) {
    return Rx.Observable.create(observer => {
        if (dt === 'random') {
            return observer.error(`error`);
        } else {
            return observer.next();
        }
    });
}
```

2 problems here though:

1: When `randomFunc` returns an error it seems that the whole chain starts over. I only need the failed one to retry.

2: `catch` never actually logs any error, even though it seems to retry on error.

For the first problem I've tried `switchMap` instead of `flatMap` like this:

```
Rx.Observable
    .interval(500)
    .take(arr.length)
    .map(idx => arr[idx])
    .switchMap(dt => randomFunc(dt)
        .catch(e => conosle.log(e))
        .retry(5)
    )
    .subscribe();
```

This way it seemed that it retried the failed ones only, but still didn't log any error and I'm not even sure `switchMap` is good here (I'm really an Rx noob).

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: `catch` might not be logging because console is spelt wrong :-)
conosle => console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There're a couple of things to be aware of. The `retry()` operator just resubscribes to its source so if you don't want to start the entire iteration again you can merge/concat the async function into the chain.

```
Rx.Observable.from(arr)
  .concatMap(val => {
    let attempts = 0;

    return Rx.Observable.of(val)
      .delay(500)
      .concatMap(val => randomFunc(val)
        .catch((err, caught) => {
          console.log('log error');
          if (attempts++ === 1) {
            return Rx.Observable.of(err);
          } else {
            return caught;
          }
        })
      );

  })
  .subscribe(val => console.log(val));

function randomFunc(dt) {
  return Rx.Observable.create(observer => {
    if (dt === 'random') {
      observer.error(`error received ${dt}`);
    } else {
      observer.next(dt);
      observer.complete();
    }
  });
}
```

See live demo: https://jsbin.com/qacamab/7/edit?js,console

This prints to console:

```
1
2
3
4
log error
log error
error received random
6
7
8
9
10
```

The `catch()` operator is the most important part. Its selector function takes two arguments:

- `err` - The error that occurred
- `caught` - The original Observable.

If we return `caught` from the selector function we'll just resubscribe to the source Observable (which is the same as `retry(1)`). Since you want to log each error message we have to use `catch()` instead of just `retry()`. By returning `Rx.Observable.of(err)` we propagate the error further and in turn it'll be received by the subscriber as `next` notification. We could also return just `Observable.empty()` to simply ignore the error.

Answer (score 1):

> When `randomFunc` returns an error it seems that the whole chain starts
>   over. I only need the failed one to retry.`

In RxJs when combining Observables together the errors will also propagate and uncaught errors will cause unsubscription.

Your idea to use catch inside the `switchMap` is correct. Though `switchMap` will only *flatten* one Observable at a time, when the next value is mapped the previous Observable will be unsubscribed (it is *switched* out)

```js
// Observable from array
Rx.Observable.from(arr)
    .concatMap(value =>
        // Put a 500 ms delay between each value
        Rx.Observable.timer(500).map(_ => value)
    )
    .flatMap(dt =>
        randomFunc(dt)
        .retryWhen(errs =>
            errs
            .do(err => console.error(err))
            // Retry at most 5 times
            .take(5)
            // Retry after 500ms
            .delay(500)
        )
    )
    .subscribe();
```

> catch never actually logs any error, even though it seems to retry on
>   error.

The function passed to catch should return an Observable e.g:

```js
Observable.throw(new Error())
    .catch(e =>
        (console.error(e), Observable.of('backup value'))
    )
    .subscribe();
```

http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-catch